# Cython memoryview error - Fatal Python error: Acquisition count is

Tags: python, cython

I'm encountering an error with Cython that I find difficult to resolve.
I have a struct ret_val which has a long[:] field called last_visited.
I'm trying to set this but get the following runtime error:

`Fatal Python error: Acquisition count is -1753032536 (line 5052)`

The following is an extract from the responsible C file at the line above:

```
/* "cymain.pyx":196
*     last = np.array([1,1,1], dtype=np.int64)
*     ret_val.last_visited = last             # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
*/

__pyx_t_9 = __Pyx_PyObject_to_MemoryviewSlice_ds_long(__pyx_v_last);

if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_9.memview)) {
    __pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; 
    __pyx_lineno = 196; 
    __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; 
    goto __pyx_L1_error;
}
__PYX_XDEC_MEMVIEW(&__pyx_v_ret_val->last_visited, 0);
__pyx_v_ret_val->last_visited = __pyx_t_9;
__pyx_t_9.memview = NULL;
__pyx_t_9.data = NULL;
```

I tried making a minimal example to reproduce the error, but then it didn't happen. Then I rewrote the function this is drawn from using the minimal example, and it failed again.

Here's a minimal example which doesn't produce the error but is, as far as I can understand, functionally identical to the error causing code:

```
cdef struct baz:
    long[:] lv
    othermodule.something* cd

cdef baz* initialise_baz(dict req):
    cdef:
        baz* ret_val = <baz *> malloc(sizeof(baz))
        long nlevels = 3

    ret_val.cd = NULL

    lv = req["key"]
    lv = np.array(lv, dtype=np.int64)
    ret_val.lv = lv

    return ret_val

def test_memview_error(req):
    cdef baz* foo
    foo = initialise_baz(req)
    print "foo.lv[2]", foo.lv[2]
```

Then call

```
import cymodule
cymodule.test_memview_error({"key":np.array([1,2,3])})
```

Comment: Can you provide the Python/Cython code, rather than the autogenerated output? Odds are the problem is there; always assume the compiler is correct and your code is wrong until you've ruled out all errors in your own code (and even then, it's still usually a problem in your code).

Comment: There is not enough information in the code you have provided to diagnose the problem.  If you cannot create a [mcve], the sad reality is that no one will be able to help you.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say it's caused by the memoryview being initialised to something random, so when it's assigned it tries to free the "old memoryview" (based on initialised memory) and hits that error. Try changing malloc to calloc...

Comment: However, I'm not 100% clear on whether you can use a memoryview as part of a c struct either... I think it's a python object so needs reference counting when the struct gets deleted etc

Comment: @DavidW, it compiles and in the short code above works. I'm utterly mystified as to why it doesn't work in my slightly more full code because it's functionally identical.

Comment: @Kevin I appreciate your point, and have posted more details. However I don't even know what an acquisition error or the number after it is/means. It's possible to provide incomplete help along the lines of "some memory is being released too soon" or "the number is negative when...". If I could isolate the problem, I wouldn't need to ask for help.

Comment: From my quick search the "acquisition number" is an alternative reference counting mechanism that allows memoryviews to be used possibly without the GIL. So in principle it should start at 1, and if it ever reaches 0 then the memory should be freed. That's why I think uninitialised memory is probably the likely culprit. I'll try to have a look at the C code generated by your simple example and see if that gives any clues...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem relates to uninitialised memory (as I said in the comments). Looking at the generated C code from your simple example:

```
/* "code.pyx":5
 * import numpy as np
 * 
 * cdef struct baz:             # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 *     long[:] lv
 *     #othermodule.something* cd
 */
struct __pyx_t_4code_baz {
  __Pyx_memviewslice lv;
};
```

(note that I've commented out `othermodule.something` for simplicity). `__Pyx_memviewslice` is defined as

```
typedef struct {
  struct __pyx_memoryview_obj *memview;
  char *data;
  Py_ssize_t shape[8];
  Py_ssize_t strides[8];
  Py_ssize_t suboffsets[8];
} __Pyx_memviewslice;
```

Some relevant code from `initialise_baz` (I've skipped some little bits here)

```
__pyx_v_ret_val = ((struct __pyx_t_4code_baz *)malloc((sizeof(struct __pyx_t_4code_baz))));
```

Note that `malloc` **does not** (necessarily) zero the memory. Thus the contents of `lv` (crucially the pointer to `memview`) are set to something arbitrary (likely what was in memory before - this obviously depends on what other code you've run before). If you use `calloc` instead of `malloc` it does zero the memory. `initialise_baz` continues:

```
  /* "code.pyx":18
 *     lv = req["key"]
 *     lv = np.array(lv, dtype=np.int64)
 *     ret_val.lv = lv             # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 * 
 *     return ret_val
 */
  __pyx_t_6 = __Pyx_PyObject_to_MemoryviewSlice_ds_long(__pyx_v_lv);
  if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_6.memview)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 18; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
  __PYX_XDEC_MEMVIEW(&__pyx_v_ret_val->lv, 0);
  __pyx_v_ret_val->lv = __pyx_t_6;
  __pyx_t_6.memview = NULL;
  __pyx_t_6.data = NULL;
```

The key line is `__PYX_XDEC_MEMVIEW` is called on the previous (arbitrary!) contents of `lv`. That's where things go wrong. `lv.memview` points to an arbitrary place, from which it reads what it thinks is an `acquisition_count`.

A superficial fix is the use `calloc` instead of `malloc`. However, even in that case `lv` never gets properly deallocated when you free `baz`, which probably causes a memory leak. I *really* don't think it makes sense to use memoryviews as part of C structures. Can you use them as part of a `cdef class` instead, where everything is taken care of properly?

Comment: Thanks this is interesting. I think I may need to rewrite in terms of C arrays as bits of this struct get passed into more basic C functions.

Comment: Perhaps also look up [public extension types](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/extension_types.html#public-and-external-extension-types) and that way you can use a `cdef class` as a struct in C.